# Visual Studio 2017 attaches to the wrong w3wp process

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

Started working this morning and quickly discovered Visual Studio 2017 debugging of my local IIS site has quit working on debug F5 startup. After a few hours of tracking things down I figured out that it is attaching to the wrong site, w3wp.exe process. I can manually attach and all is well.

If I stop the site that VS has this affinity to I get the standard ... Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to connect to the remote server'

Anybody know how Visual Studio chooses the w3wp.exe process that the debugger wants to attach to on debug starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved after half a day of time spent and don't have an exact resolution. This project is a Web Site running on a particular port at same level as the Default Web Site. The fix was adding in the port to the project properties page 'Project Url' and removing it from showing up underneath the Default Web Site. I never thought the port was included in the project Url where the Virtual directory is created since original setup a few weeks back. If my memory is wrong then something removed the port from this Project Url setting.

I also noted that for some reason this site showed up in IIS Manager in 2 locations, under the Default Site as well as the site itself. When originally setup the Default Site was deleted and added back later but all had been working fine since then.

After more thought I also recall that the I discovered when the site did not first run in debugger it had been changed to run under IIS Express. I don't know why that happened unless I did seem sleep coding over the weekend.

Comment: Since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours, thanks for your sharing:)